# C++ Embded lambda in initializer list for const vector member

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I have a class that has a `const vector` member that holds unique pointers to some objects. When constructed, the `sequence` object should steal the ownership of the vector of unique pointers that is passed to the constructor so that the sequence object is now the owner of the objects that were owned by the unique pointers in the vector parameter.

```
class sequence
{
    const std::vector< std::unique_ptr< statement > > m_statements;

    sequence( std::vector< std::unique_ptr< statement > > & statements );
};
```

The first time I tried to implement the constructor, I did the following :

```
sequence::sequence( vector< unique_ptr< statement > > & statements )
    m_statements( statements )
{
}
```

But of course this does not compile since one can't copy-construct a `unique_ptr` and thus can't copy-construct a `vector`.

C++ doesn't allow to initialize const members in the body of the constructor (like Java does with final members), but only within the initializer list. Thus, one possible solution could be to drop the `const` modifier of `m_statement` and, using a loop, move the content from one vector to the other in the body of the constructor.

But I want to keep this `const` modifier.

So I came up with another solution that seems to compile, but because I'm new to C++11, I'm not certain about what it does exacly. The idea was to embed the loop described above into a lambda function so that I could initialize `m_statement` within the initializer list using a loop and still keep the `const` modifier on `m_statement`.

```
sequence::sequence( vector< unique_ptr< const statement > > & statements ) :
    m_statements(([ & statements ] {
        vector< unique_ptr< const statement > > copied_vec;
        for( auto & stm : statements )
            copied_vec.push_back( move( stm ) );
        return copied_vec;
    })())
{
}
```

This compiles. But I'm not sure about what happens starting at the return statement of the lambda function.

I assume that a copy of copied_vec made and returned. What happens when you return by value a vector of unique pointers ? Is it a correct way to do what I want, despite being weird, or must I just drop the `const` modifier on `m_statetent` ? Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question on how your code works but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282204/proper-way-of-transferring-ownership-of-a-stdvector-stdunique-ptr-int-t) shows you the right way to `move` the vector.

Comment: You create a lambda, then you call it. Clever, albeit unnecessary.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. I'm speechless to see how simple it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Am I missing a reason why a move constructor can't be used?

```
sequence::sequence( vector< unique_ptr< statement > > && statements )
    m_statements( std::move(statements) )
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just didn't think about that. Though i'd still like to know what happens when i'm copying `copied_vec` using the return by value.

Comment: Depending on "details" I think you're likely to get some form of RVO. I think with C++17 it's even mandated (again, depending on details).

Comment: Thanks. But ignoring that kind of implicit compiler optimization, what happens when you copy a vector of unique pointers ? The ownership is treansfered from the pointers of the source vector to the newly created vector's pointers ?

Comment: @Virus721: You cannot copy a vector of unique_ptrs. **Edit** [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387367b1cd7f5af1)

Comment: Not with a straight up copy, but your situation isn't quite a straight up copy. If you did use a real copy then you'd get a compiler error because `std::unique_ptr` has deleted the copy constructor and assignment operators.

Comment: @KayEss So this only compiles because the compiler is able to get rid of a copy thanks to RVO ? If you disable any compiler optimization, isn't it going to compile anymore ?

Comment: RVO isn't dependant on optimisation level, and there are special rules for the return value of a function that allow the compiler to automatically invoke a move even when the code looks like it does a copy.

Comment: @KayEss Also one more question please. Why is the `std::move` call necessary since the parameter is already a r-value reference ? Isn't `std::move` only a cast that generare a r-value references from something that isn't one ?

Comment: Good Q. I didn't run this through a compiler. It might not be necessary, but I put them in anyway to mark where the ownership moves.

Comment: @Virus721 Once a object has a name it is a lvalue.  Even though you got it as a rvalue reference it is a lvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver But in that case, isn't it up to the caller of the constructor to call `std::move` ?

Comment: @Virus721 Yes and no.  The rvalue reference constructor will take a temporary or a vector that `move` has been applied to.  Once you get to `m_statements( std::move(statements) )` `statements` is a named object so it a lvaue again.  In order to move it into the member variable you need to call `move` again.

Comment: @Virus721: That is one way for it to happen. Alternatively, if a function is simply returning a `vector<unique_ptr<statement>>`, then that object is already an r-value, and this constructor will be chosen without any explicit `move`