# Common interface with a wrapper around std::variant or unions

Tags: c++, interface, dispatch

This question is related to [Enforcing a common interface with std::variant without inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434897/enforcing-a-common-interface-with-stdvariant-without-inheritance).

The difference between that question and this one, is that I wouldn't mind inheritance, I am simply looking for the following structs/classes...

```
struct Parent { virtual int get() = 0; };
struct A : public Parent { int get() { return 1; } };
struct B : public Parent { int get() { return 2; } };
struct C : public Parent { int get() { return 3; } };
```

... to be AUTOMATICALLY "assembled" into a template:

```
template<typename PARENT, typename... TYPES>
struct Multi
{
    // magic happens here
}

// The type would accept assignment just like an std::variant would...
Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiA = A();
Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiB = B();
Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiC = C();

// And it would also be able to handle virtual dispatch as if it were a Parent*
Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiB = B();
multiB.get(); // returns 2
```

Is this possible? If so, how? I would like to avoid working with handling pointers, as the use of std::variant/unions is intended to make memory contiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't automagically set this up to allow `multiB.get()`, but you *can* allow `multiB->get()` or `(*multiB).get()` and even implicit conversion, by providing operator overloads:

```cpp
template<typename Base, typename... Types>
struct Multi : std::variant<Types...>
{
    using std::variant<Types...>::variant;

    operator Base&()               { return getref<Base>(*this); }
    Base& operator*()              { return static_cast<Base&>(*this); }
    Base* operator->()             { return &static_cast<Base&>(*this); }

    operator const Base&() const   { return getref<const Base>(*this); }
    const Base& operator*() const  { return static_cast<const Base&>(*this); }
    const Base* operator->() const { return &static_cast<const Base&>(*this); }

private:
    template<typename T, typename M>
    static T& getref(M& m) {
        return std::visit([](auto&& x) -> T& { return x; }, m);
    }
};
```

You've probably encountered this kind of thing before when using iterators from the standard library.

Example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiA = A();
    Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiB = B();
    Multi<Parent, A, B, C> multiC = C();

    // Dereference
    std::cout << (*multiA).get();
    std::cout << (*multiB).get();
    std::cout << (*multiC).get();

    // Indirection
    std::cout << multiA->get();
    std::cout << multiB->get();
    std::cout << multiC->get();

    // Implicit conversion
    auto fn = [](Parent& p) { std::cout << p.get(); };
    fn(multiA);
    fn(multiB);
    fn(multiC);
}
```

Output:

```
123123123
```